# SWIFT: Moving each child node along line path separately

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm following the tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/80586/make-line-drawing-game-sprite-kit-swift#

All is going well except that each one of the 'pig' child nodes from the Pig class all move together; in that when I draw a line for one node all the nodes follow the same path. If I then draw a line for another node, they all then follow that one.

What I'm trying to work out is how to make each pig node follow it's own path.

I've tried naming the nodes 'pig1', 'pig2' etc, while 'touches begin' does show specifically which node I'm touching, it seems the line path when created for one pig is applied to all and not each individual pig node.

I've contacted the author but with no reply, I would greatly appreciate any advice, be it another tutorial (can't find any myself).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, despite thinking I was following the code correctly, I stupidly made the wayPoints array (which held the line coordinates) a global var for the Pig class instead of a object (node) specific.

Changed position of var declaration and all is good.